# Unicode strings in pure C++

Tags: c++, string, unicode, cross-platform

How to arrange correct processing of Unicode strings using pure C++?

What I mean is, when you put your unicode string into std::string and count its length, sometimes you get like 10 characters for 5-chars-long string.

How do they do it in serious open-source programs? How do they do it in a cross-platform manner? How do you tie it to file i/o and stdin/stdout streams?

Thanks.

Comment: 'Serious open-source programs' do not count characters. It's almost always useless, [seriosly](http://utf8everywhere.org/#myth.strlen).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's [Boost.Locale](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/locale/doc/html/index.html), which is written in C++, wraps the ICU library, and provides a nice, non-alien interface to it.

For Unicode work, my first choice would be Boost.Locale, followed by ICU directly (if there is something that Boost.Locale doesn't wrap yet).

Answer (score 4):

`std::[w]string`, contrary to popular belief, has no Unicode support whatsoever. They both operate only on `[w]char[_t]` units, in an encoding agnostic way.

If you only need basic Unicode support in the form of length and conversions and encoding verification, there is [utfcpp](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/), which provides a beautiful C++ interface for these operations.

Application frameworks like Qt and wxWdigets do provide their own `string` classes, which offer better Unicode support, but often tying you to use the whole framework throughout your code.

Aside from that, there is [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/), which is *the* standard Unicode implementation around today.

A work in progress by one of the C++ masters on this website is [ogonek](https://bitbucket.org/martinhofernandes/ogonek). you can surely contact the author through the [`Lounge<C++>`](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec) StackOverflow chat room to ask for details on his progress.

Comment: Woot. Good rundown and nice plug for the robot

Answer (score 2):

This is how: http://www.utf8everywhere.org

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked http://site.icu-project.org already?

Answer (score 1):

ICU is currently *the* Unicode library. If you want cross-platform Unicode support, ICU is basically the only place to get it.

If only its interface wasn't more unfriendly than the wrong end of an automatic shotgun.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [wxWidgets](http://wxwidgets.org/) to do this. It makes for easy conversion from std::string to their string type wxString. It's not ideal, but it works well, is simple and portable.